# Sqlite error: statements in progress when no statements should be

Tags: java, sqlite

I've been having this issue for a while haven't understood why it is happening. In my application I interact a lot with the database and turn autocommit on and off based on what is going on. However, at any time the user may use a VACUUM on the database to help reduce the file size except it gives an error.

```
// org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (cannot VACUUM - SQL statements in progress)
// The error above for this:
if(!con.getAutoCommit()) {
    con.commit();
    con.setAutoCommit(true);
}
s.execute("VACUUM"); // on this line
```

On startup a couple items are selected from the database (1 to 5 rows at most) and I am able to do the vacuum just fine. After I do a selection that selects a couple hundred rows that joins several tables, I get this error when attempting to VACUUM. As an example of what those queries look like:

```
// Inside a PreparedStatement
SELECT * FROM tableV 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT tableV.v_id, count(tableV.v_id) as c_count FROM tableV 
    LEFT JOIN tableC on tableV.v_id = tableC.v_id 
    GROUP BY tableV.v_id 
    ORDER BY c_count DESC) AS cc ON cc.v_id = tableV.v_id 
LEFT JOIN tableP ON tableP.c_id = tableV.c_id 
WHERE tableV.v_id IN ( 
    SELECT v_id FROM tableVG 
    LEFT JOIN tableGiG ON tableVG.gi_id = tableGiG.gi_id 
    LEFT JOIN tableG ON tableG.g_id = tableGiG.g_id 
    WHERE g_name = ?) 
ORDER BY tableV.publish_date DESC

// Inside a PreparedStatement
SELECT * FROM gitem_list 
LEFT JOIN tableGi ON tableGi.type_id = gitem_list.type_id 
LEFT JOIN tableGiG ON tableGiG.gi_id = gitem_list.gi_id 
LEFT JOIN tableG ON tableG.g_id = tableGiG.g_id 
WHERE g_name = ?
```

I've tried closing the PreparedStatement and ResultSet after the query with no affect. The queries completed and everything loads fine in the application, why does it say that statements are still happening? I don't change the connection or statement.

Comment: "Statements in progress" means that some `PreparedStatement` or `ResultSet` was not closed.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that. I added close statements to every method that has those two and it is working like it should.

Comment: Don't forget to close blob I/O handles either if you have those. Since I just spent ages debugging that personally.